# How can one show that $N(A)\cap R(A)=\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove that
>   $N(A)\cap R(A)=\{0\}$ where $A$ is an $m×n$ matrix and $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$, $R(A)$ is the row space of $A$.

[Using their orthogonality we can say that the statement is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945982/show-that-nulla-cap-imageat-0?rq=1). But I am interested in another method. I am trying to prove the *dimension* of intersection of the subspaces is $0$. How can I do that?

Comment: If $A$ is a square matrix, then in general $N(A) \cap R(A) \ne \{0\}$ ! Question: what are the properties of $A$ ?

Comment: @Fred please give me a counter example ...

Comment: It might be of some use to clearly define the row-space. Is it a vector space consisting of the span of the rows of the matrix? If so, does it consist of row vectors, or are they all transposed to be column vectors? BTW, I suspect Fred's comment comes from the fact that $R(A)$ is sometimes used to denote the *range* of $A$ rather than the row-space; under that interpretation, the intersection may indeed be nonempty.

Comment: Yes, the row space is the vector space spanned by the rows of the matrix $A$

Comment: A counterexample would be $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \end{pmatrix}$ (a $1\times 2$-matrix over the complex numbers). Here, $N\left(A\right)$ and $R\left(A\right)$ both contain the vector $\left(1,i\right)$ (if you equate row vectors with column vectors). The reason why this does not happen for real numbers is that the dot product is positive definite over $\mathbb{R}$ (so that no nonzero vector is orthogonal to itself). And this is why you need to use orthogonality (or something equivalent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to consider the intersection of $N(A)$ and $R(A)$ (row space), you have to define the latter as the column space of $A^T$, because the span of the rows of $A$ lives in a different vector space than $N(A)$.

With that interpretation, let $v\in N(A)\cap R(A)$. Then there exists $x$ such that $v=A^Tx$. Also $Av=0$, so $AA^Tx=0$; in particular
$$
0=x^TAA^Tx=(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx)=v^Tv
$$
implying $v=0$.

Here $X^T$ denotes the transpose matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonality **is** how you prove this, since it's a fundamental definition of the null space of a matrix: the null space is the space that is orthogonal to the row space.  We can make some progress with dimensions, but we'll have to return to the orthogonality argument eventually:

If by some reason the two spaces had non trivial intersection, then some nonzero vectors in the null space could be represented as linear combinations of those in the row space.  If that were the case, then some sub-space of the row space would be the basis for a sub-space of the null space, and therefore the some nonzero vectors of one are linearly dependent on nonzero vectors in the other. However, there is a theorem that states that orthogonal sets of vectors are always linearly independent.  This is a contradiction unless the only vector in the intersection is the zero vector.